# How would I make this line work?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a program that graphs a line based on data inputted by the user. (It's based on the slope form/equation). I am using the Canvas to graph my equation. I've been having a problem graphing the equation in a way that lets it adapt to the scaling (which is based on how large the numbers inputted are.)

How can I make the graphed equation (line) fit the graph as the canvas scales?

Here's my code:

```
var c=document.getElementById("graph_");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
graph_.style.backgroundColor="white";

// This is used to define the parameters of the canvas. Variables a and b are the x and y intercepts of the linear function.

var z0=Math.max(Math.abs(a),Math.abs(b));
var z=Math.round(z0);           
var z1=Math.round(z);
var z2=z*2
// alert(z1);           
// alert(z2);`

//The code below is used to properly scale the canvas and lines so they can accomodate larger numbers   
var scale = 2*z/360;
var offsetX = 150;
var offsetY = 75


ctx.translate((-c.width /2 * scale) + offsetX,(-c.height / 2 * scale) + offsetY);                   
ctx.scale(scale,scale);    


        var lw = scale/2
        var xnew = 360/2+360/2*a
        var ynew = 360/2-360/2*b
        alert(xnew);    
        alert(ynew);

        //The two lines drawn below are the axises of the graph

                    ctx.lineWidth = 2/lw;
                        ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.moveTo(150, 40000*-1);
            ctx.lineTo(150, 40000);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.lineWidth = 1/lw;
        ctx.moveTo(400000*-1, 75);
        ctx.lineTo(40000, 75);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#8B8682";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        //var xmax = 400000 - b 
        //var xmax1 = xmax/s
        //var ymax =    400000*s
        //var ymax1 = ymax + b

// The code below graphs the equation. 

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth = 1/lw;
                  ctx.moveTo(xnew, 180);
          ctx.lineTo(180, ynew);
          // ctx.lineTo(xmax, ymax)
          // ctx.lineTo(xmax*-1, ymax*-1)
          ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
          ctx.stroke();
```

Here is the coding for the whole page: 
As you can see the line, if drawn at all, doesn't become long enough, like it should. (linear lines are always infinite, so the line should be going across the WHOLE graph, not a small portion.)

```
var canwith=360
var canheight=360

// alert(window.innerWidth)

 function doSolve() {
var s=''
var x1 = document.getElementById('x1').value
var y1 = document.getElementById('y1').value
var x2 = document.getElementById('x2').value 
var y2 = document.getElementById('y2').value 
var m 
var b
var a 

    try {
        if ((x2 - x1)==0) {
            m='Undefined'
            b='Undefined'
            a=x1 
        } else {
            m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
            b = (y2-x2*m)
            a = (-b/m)
        }


        s += 'Coordinates are: ('
        s += x1
        s += ','
        s += y1
        s += '),('
        s += x2
        s += ','
        s += y2
        s += ')'
        s += '<br>Slope:'
        s += m
        s +='<br>y intercept:'
        s += b
        s += '<br>x intercept:' 
        s += a

        if (m=='undefined') {
            s += '<br>Equation: x = ' + x1      
        } else {
            s += '<br>Equation: y = '
            if (m!=0) {
                if (m!=1) {
                    s += m + 'x' 
                } else {
                    s += 'x' 
                }
            }
            if (b!=0) {
                if (b>0) {
                    s += ' + ' + b
                } else {
                    s += ' - ' + b*-1
                }
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('outputx').innerHTML=s

    } catch (e) {alert(e.message)}  

    try {

        var c=document.getElementById("graph_");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        graph_.style.backgroundColor="white";
        var z0=Math.max(Math.abs(a),Math.abs(b));
        var z=Math.round(z0);           
        var z1=Math.round(z);
        var z2=z*2
        // alert(z1);   
        // alert(z2);

           var scale = 2*z/360;
           var offsetX = 150;
           var offsetY = 75


    ctx.translate((-c.width /2 * scale) + offsetX,(-c.height / 2 * scale) + offsetY);                   
    ctx.scale(scale,scale);    


        var lw = scale/2
        var xnew = 360/2+360/2*a
        var ynew = 360/2-360/2*b
        alert(xnew);    
        alert(ynew);


        ctx.lineWidth = 2/lw;
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(150, 40000*-1);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 40000);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.lineWidth = 1/lw;
        ctx.moveTo(400000*-1, 75);
        ctx.lineTo(40000, 75);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#8B8682";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        var xmax = 400000 - b 
        var xmax1 = xmax/s
        var ymax =  400000*s
        var ymax1 = ymax + b

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth = 1/lw;
          ctx.moveTo(xnew, 180);
          ctx.lineTo(180, ynew);
          ctx.lineTo(xmax, ymax)
          ctx.lineTo(xmax*-1, ymax*-1)
          ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
          ctx.stroke();                                         

    } catch (e) {alert(e.message)}
```

}

Comment: This is not particularly clear. Could you please be more specific in the stated problem?

Comment: How can I make the graphed equation (line) fit the graph as the canvas scales?

Comment: By 'canvas scales' do you mean zoom-in/zoom-out of the plotted graph or do you want that the entire graph fits into the canvas?

Comment: the canvas zooms in/out in order to fit the maximum x/y intercept. My line isn't scaling with the canvas properly.

Comment: I could zoom-in/out your line without problems varying the scale factor in the line `var scale = 2*z/360;`.  To zoom-in, I just used `var scale = 5*z/360;` and `var scale = 0.7*z/360;` to zoom-out. (The line parameters used area `a = 10` and `b = -2`).  The only noted problem could find is that the line doesn't intercept the axis in the drawing if you keep zooming-in. Please, could you indicate more info so I could reproduce the stated problem?

Comment: I'll edit my question to include all the coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couln't cope with your code, so I made my own implementation adjusting to your visual requirements, hope this fix the problem:

```
try {
    var c = document.getElementById("graph_");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    graph_.style.backgroundColor="white";

    var w = c.width;
    var h = c.height;

    var xAxisSize = 40;
    var yAxisSize = 40;    

    var scaleFactorX = w / xAxisSize;
    var scaleFactorY = -(h / yAxisSize);        

    var offsetX = -10;
    var offsetY = -10;

    ctx.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
    ctx.translate((xAxisSize / 2) + offsetX, -((yAxisSize / 2) + offsetY));

    ctx.lineWidth = 3 / scaleFactorX;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-xAxisSize, 0);
    ctx.lineTo( xAxisSize, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#8B8682";        
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.lineWidth = 3 / scaleFactorY;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, -yAxisSize);
    ctx.lineTo(0,  yAxisSize);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#8B8682";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.lineWidth = 3 / scaleFactorY;
    ctx.beginPath();
    var xx1 = -xAxisSize - offsetX;
    var yy1 = m * xx1 + b;
    var xx2 =  xAxisSize + offsetX;
    var yy2 = m * xx2 + b;        
    ctx.moveTo(xx1, yy1);
    ctx.lineTo(xx2,yy2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();  
} catch (e) { 
    alert(e.message) 
}
```

[image]

Comment: `m` is the slope in your code, I just replaced the second `try/catch` block of your code, everything is the same (the funcion, function name, the first `try/catch` block, etc)

Comment: The axises don't seem to scale properly. The axises stay the same, though that might be what you were intending. Either way, thank you!

Comment: Yes, it was intended, but if you want to scale them, just double their size at drawing, like this `ctx.moveTo(-2 * xAxisSize, 0); ctx.lineTo(2* xAxisSize, 0);` and `ctx.moveTo(0, -2 * yAxisSize); ctx.lineTo(0, 2 * yAxisSize);`, you're welcome